# How to remove class="quantity" in Woocommerce qty field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How to remove `<div class="quantity">` in woocommerce_quantity_input (Woocommerce)

```
$quantity=woocommerce_quantity_input();

$quantity_field= str_replace('<div class="quantity">', '', $quantity);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace` for this!

```
preg_match('/^(<div class="quantity">)(.*?)(<\/div>)$/', woocommerce_quantity_input(), $matches);

// this will output whatever is in the middle of <div class="quantity"></div>
$quantity_field = $matches[2];
```

*Fiddle*: **[PHPFiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/64a741248f6ee20ef956ad698e8c0ba162c27ebb)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are overiding woocommerce plugin files, remove class quantity from global/quantity-input.php